# Error while importing CSV for category in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

While importing the CSV file with category I am getting the error

**The category ID cannot be the same as the Root category ID or the Home category ID.**

Along with a list of errors are listed but this one seems to be the actual issue. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Show us your CSV file. ;) Maybe you've seen this post on PS forum : http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/223600-error-on-importing-categories/ , it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because in you CSV file, you have set the ID column?

But in Import Category in Prestashop, you h'ave to begin the ID to 3 because in default, in Prestashop you have the Root Category and the Home Category that use ID 1 and ID 2 !

:)

Comment: Yes, I think the same of @kminhtri. +1

Answer (score 1):

Check & Keep, in the 2nd step. If you have Root & Home also in the CSV

```
Lines to skip = 3
```

[image]